# Can I upload an app compiled in sdk 7 to the App-store?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, itunes

Last year (March) I have developed and uploaded an iPhone-iPad app, it was compiled in sdk 7. Now I plan modify this app and upload a new version. So my question is: Does the App-Store allow apps compiled in sdk 7 ? or, Should I compile this app in sdk 8?.

Thank you.

Comment: No. Yes. Shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning June 1st 2015, updates to apps compiled with older than the iOS 8 SDK will no longer be accepted: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04082015a

You may have till then to upload.  After that you will have to rebuild the app using iOS 8 SDK (or newer).  (But starting earlier might be a good idea.)